# Recursion going back instead of exiting (c#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, recursion, return

I have a problem.
The recursion is working fine as long as Item.Length > 0.
When Item.Length == 0 it skips the line: `GetId(Id, result, Items);`
Goes to the line `return Id;` with the correct Id,
and then instead of leaving the function and return the Id,
it goes straight to the line `GetId(Id, result, Items);`
with the PREVIOUS Id, result and Items.

Where is the problem?

```
private string GetId(string Id, List<something> result, string[] Items)
{
     try
     {
            // some code

            if (Items.Length != 0)
                  GetId(Id, result, Items);
     }
     catch (Exception e){}

     return Id;
}
```

Comment: Please post complete code

Answer (score 3):

Well yes, it would. Look at your code:

```
if (Items.Length != 0)
    GetId(Id, result, Items);
```

Which part of that says that it should exit the method? It doesn't. It just calls `GetId` and completely ignores the result.

Instead, you probably meant to return the value returned by the recursive call:

```
if (Items.Length != 0)
    return GetId(Id, result, Items);
```

As an aside, I hope your real exception handling is rather better - catching `Exception` is usually a bad idea, and silently swallowing it is pretty much *always* a bad idea...

Comment: Even with return, won't this go into an infinite loop? He's calling the method recursively, with the same data every time. So if it does not hit his block `(Length != 0)` the first time, it never will.

Comment: yeh, i handle it differently, just didn't want to copy the entire thing here

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen: I would hope that's handled with "some code". It's certainly far from the clearest question in the world...

Comment: the some code is fine! refer it as id++ or whatever... but, even with the "return" keyword it is still going to return id, back to return getId(id, result, items) with the old value, and back to return Id with this same old value and exits. (when it goes to the getId(..) line, it doesn't enter the function, just mess up all the values

Comment: @user990635: I'm afraid at this point your question is far too confusing to answer. You've missed out important code, not explained what you're trying to do, and your description of what's going wrong is hard to follow. You should try to write a short but *complete* example so that we can see *exactly* what's happening. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I added the code.. I just didn't think it will matter. I thought it will be more confusing

Comment: @user990635: If this is now your real code, then your comment about handling exceptions differently is completely untrue. It's still not a short but complete example, you haven't explained what it's trying to achieve, nor can I follow your explanation of what happens when you use my fix. The question still needs a lot of work.

Comment: no, it is without the exception part. I meant it is what goes instead of : //some code

Comment: @JonSkeet - Yup, this is quite a mess actually.

Comment: ok, ok, I tried my best to explain better! all edited :)

Comment: @user990635: There's no explanation at all. You **still** haven't said what you're trying to do, and this **still** isn't a short but complete example. Sorry, but I'm done here - I hope the answer is helpful to you, but I'm not going to keep asking for the same information time and time again, and not getting anywhere.